# Why am I unable to download Landsat 8 geotiff data from the USGS site?

Tags: data, download, landsat-8

I seem to have an issue with not being able to download geotiff Landsat 8 data from te USGS site.  After i find the image i would like to download and proceed to download the Level 1 geotiff option is disabled and I am only allowed to download the LandsatLook jpeg images.

I downloaded data from this site before but perhaps I am overlooking something.

I tried both http://glovis.usgs.gov/ and http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

Screen capture showing the disabled "dimmed" option:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Landsat 8 data is [offline for recalibration](http://landsat.usgs.gov/calibration_notices.php) from 3 Feb 2013 for up to approx 50 days.

Comment: Oh no! That's not good. Not good at all.  Thanks for clearing it up. Can the data be downloaded from alternate locations?

Comment: try glcf, there also you will find good source